# Python xml parsing multiple node with xml.etree

Tags: python, xml, parsing

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree
from xml.etree import ElementTree
file_name = 'pubmed21n0001.xml'
full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('data', file_name))

dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)
pubmed = dom.findall('PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation')

for p in pubmed:
        LastName = p.find('Article/AuthorList/Author/LastName').text
        ForeName = p.find('Article/AuthorList/Author/ForeName').text
        Initials = p.find('Article/AuthorList/Author/Initials').text
        print('{}_{}_{}'.format(LastName, ForeName, Initials))
```

> this is the python code i wrote

```
<root>
  <PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
      <Article PubModel="Print">
        <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Makar</LastName>
            <ForeName>A B</ForeName>
            <Initials>AB</Initials>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>McMartin</LastName>
            <ForeName>K E</ForeName>
            <Initials>KE</Initials>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Palese</LastName>
            <ForeName>M</ForeName>
            <Initials>M</Initials>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Tephly</LastName>
            <ForeName>T R</ForeName>
            <Initials>TR</Initials>
          </Author>
        </AuthorList>
      </Article>
    </MedlineCitation>
  </PubmedArticle>
</root>
```

How can I parse multiple name?
if I run the code only one name is printed
this is concised version of pubmed21n001.xml file
there is a lot  in the orignial file

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<root>
  <PubmedArticle>
    <MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
      <Article PubModel="Print">
        <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Makar</LastName>
            <ForeName>A B</ForeName>
            <Initials>AB</Initials>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>McMartin</LastName>
            <ForeName>K E</ForeName>
            <Initials>KE</Initials>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Palese</LastName>
            <ForeName>M</ForeName>
            <Initials>M</Initials>
          </Author>
          <Author ValidYN="Y">
            <LastName>Tephly</LastName>
            <ForeName>T R</ForeName>
            <Initials>TR</Initials>
          </Author>
        </AuthorList>
      </Article>
    </MedlineCitation>
  </PubmedArticle>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for a in root.findall('.//Author'):
    print(f'{a.find("LastName").text}_{a.find("ForeName").text}_{a.find("Initials").text}')
```

output

```
Makar_A B_AB
McMartin_K E_KE
Palese_M_M
Tephly_T R_TR
```

Answer (score 0):

Go further into parentheses:

```py
# Find a list of author nodes
pubmed = dom.findall('PubmedArticle/MedlineCitation/Article/AuthorList/Author')

for p in pubmed:
        # Now you're able to access props directly
        LastName = p.find('LastName').text
        ForeName = p.find('ForeName').text
        Initials = p.find('Initials').text
```

Comment: this worked great but I forgot to mention that I need to divide name by each Pubmedarticle
can you help me with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67383045/python-xml-parsing-with-xml-etree)

Comment: @hyunsuk: If it worked great for the problem in the question, show gratitude by marking the answer as accepted.