# Python xml parsing with xml.etree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree
file_name = 'sex.xml'
full_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('data', file_name))

dom = ElementTree.parse(full_file)
pubmed = dom.findall('PubmedArticle')
name = dom.findall('PubmedArticle/AuthorList/Author')

for p in pubmed:
    pmid = p.find('PMID').text
    print('PMID: {}'.format(pmid))
    for n in name:
       LastName = n.find('LastName').text
       print('{}'.format(LastName))
    print('========\n')
```

I want to get names for each PubmedArticle

but this code gets the whole name at once

```
<root>
  <PubmedArticle>
      <PMID>1</PMID>
      <AuthorList>
        <Author>
          <LastName>Makar</LastName>
        </Author>
        <Author>
          <LastName>McMartin</LastName>
        </Author>
       </AuthorList>
  </PubmedArticle>
  <PubmedArticle>
      <PMID>2</PMID>
      <AuthorList>
        <Author>
          <LastName>Palese</LastName>
        </Author>
        <Author>
          <LastName>Tephly</LastName>
        </Author>
       </AuthorList>
  </PubmedArticle>
</root>
```

How can I get names divied by PMID like this

[result]

PMID 1: Makar, McMartin

PMID 2: Palese, Tephly

Answer (score 0):

`pubmed` and `name` are two independent lists. You have to query the authors for each article separately:

```
articles = dom.findall('PubmedArticle')
for article in articles:
    pmid = article.findtext('PMID')
    print(f'PMID: {pmid}')
    authors = article.findall('AuthorList/Author')
    for author in authors:
        lastname = author.findtext('LastName')
        print(lastname)
    print('========\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all PubmedArticle:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('med.xml').getroot()

lname_list = []
for med in root.findall(".//PubmedArticle"):
    for con in med.iter():
        if con.tag == "PMID":
            pmid = con.text
        if con.tag == "LastName":
            lname_list.append(con.text)
            

    print(f"PMID {pmid} : ", end='')
    print(', '.join(lname_list))
    lname_list = []
    print('='*8+'\n')
```

Output:

```
PMID 1 : Makar, McMartin
========

PMID 2 : Palese, Tephly
========
```

Or as an alternative:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('med.xml').getroot()

names = []
for pubmed in root.findall('PubmedArticle'):
    pmid = pubmed.find('.//PMID').text
    for name in pubmed.findall('.//LastName'):
        names.append(name.text)
        
    print(f"PMID {pmid} : ", end='')
    print(', '.join(names))
    names = []
    print('='*8+'\n')
```